# Introduction to tf installation error

Tags: rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I found that when following the command "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ros-tutorials ros-hydro-geometry-tutorials rviz", I got an error. I resolved this by changing "rviz" to "ros-hydro-rviz". Is this the correct way to do this or should it be working with just "rviz"?
http://wiki.ros.org/action/login/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206121/introduction-to-tf-installation-error/) by [nbanyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19003/nbanyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2015-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks you're right. Fixed [here](http://wiki.ros.org/action/diff/tf/Tutorials/Introduction%20to%20tf?action=diff&rev1=99&rev2=100)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19003/nbanyk/) on 2015-03-27**:
Thanks for the quick turnaround!